# PWA Add to Home did different behavior in Android device

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I have 3 Android devices.

1. Android 7.1, Chrome v71 latest version
2. Android 8.0, Chrome v71 latest version
3. Anrdoid 8.1, Chrome v71 latest version

I tested PWA's "Add to home" feature and some weird behavior in chrome browser

First device always ask "Add to home" when access website even though already installed it.

Second and Third device only ask "Add to home" when PWA not installed.

Also I tested Android Simulator v8.0 was same thing first device.

I have no idea why each browsers show different work.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/a2hs-updates), starting in Chrome 68 on Android, Chrome will no longer show the add to home screen banner.

> If the site meets the [add to home screen criteria](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/#criteria), Chrome will show the mini-infobar. Then, if the user clicks on the mini-infobar, or you call `prompt()` on the `beforeinstallprompt` event from within a user gesture, Chrome will show a modal add to home screen dialog.

Comment: Hi abielita. these devices are enough about add to home criteria. My point is same browser did not show same behavior.